# How does one create a timer or counter in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I'm thinking that the computer keeps time by using the CMOS battery. It keeps time by counting the number of pulses per second produced by the battery, a counter.

My confusion is how exactly a module such as time in python works, or any other application with a timer for that matter. I'm assuming that it will have to access directly, or indirectly to a lower level module built into the operating system ie; written in assembly? If this is the case, could someone shed some light on how exactly assembly code can update a register without being able to check every x amount of time. Surely the computer must need to check if the register has changed, which would require time keeping to check periodically?

Comment: What do you mean by "registry"?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, I probably am at something this low level. A register is a memory address where a variable is stored. This variable could be a binary value for true or false; whether or not the battery produced a voltage, i guess. How does it check if this value is True or False?

Comment: Your question says registry, not register. What does checking a register have to do with either time keeping or creating a counter in asm?

Comment: Usually the CMOS clock is read very intermittently by an OS since it is usually a slow operation. Usually an OS at bootup will set up a timer to fire at a fixed interval, read the CMOS clock, convert that into a number of ticks since a certain date/time and then on each timer interrupt the tick count is increased. Usually an OS allows you to query this tick count (which can be converted back into a time/date). How you get the timer tick will vary from OS to OS, and you don't mention what OS and hardware your are using.

Comment: Most modern OSes on x86 use `rdtsc` as a timesource (with a scale factors to convert from reference cycles to wall-clock time).   e.g. on Linux, the `gettimeofday()` system call doesn't actually enter the kernel at all, it runs `rdtsc` in user space and scales the result with data exported by the kernel.  See https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/ (the VDSO part).

Comment: And BTW, batteries supply DC power, not pulses.  The battery *powers an oscillator* and some digital logic to count those cycles and update the CMOS time.

Comment: Thank you guys very much, I have plenty to do and read about.

Comment: `A register is a memory address where a variable is stored` no, a register is a physical memory storage and not an address. It isn't in the same normal memory address space either

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: I think the OP is thinking of a memory-mapped I/O register, not a CPU register.  Calling it somewhere "a variable is stored" is still a terrible mangling of what an I/O register does.

Answer (score 1):

What does assembly have to do with this or any other language?

There is an RTC, real time clock that is battery backed.  This keeps your time when the computer is "off".  The so called CMOS (BIOS, etc) is a battery backed ram that keeps your settings when the computer is "off" as well as the computers bootloader.  It simply reads the time from the RTC.

There is a timer, which you can set/change and enable an interrupt at some interval, historically that was set and the interrupt came at some rate, and lead to the possibility of using that to keep time.  X number of ticks per second/hour/day/year.  A really bad source of time once virtual machines came into play as you may have noticed the time would drift dramatically.

All software running on the primary processor, be it "bios" software, the operating system, ... boils down into machine code, and most compilers generate assembly first then assemble because that is the sane way to do it.  If you are running bare metal on an x86 (and if this timer still exists, or other better timers may now also exist), you can setup an interrupt handler to handle a periodic interrupt from a timer.  Since you are baremetal you can choose the interrupt rate and your epoch time (just read the RTC) and then count ticks.  And if you dont have the right priorities set then you might miss one or some and start to lose track of time.  Assembly is naturally the "easiest" as you dont have language issues getting in the way of setting up and hitting the handler, but still solvable in other languages.

Although not a hard and fast rule Python like JAVA, etc compile to a virtual machine "instruction set", and then there is an interpreter targeted at the actual instruction set.  Doesnt mean you cant compile these to the target in theory and probably in practice.  The timer has nothing to do with this, do these languages allow, are they setup to be used bare metal and handle interrupts?  Are there designed in hooks for interrupt based callbacks into functions in this language?  None of this is relevant for the time function in python, you would only need to have the vm ask the os for the current time here and there for that function/feature to work.

You want to get the time in an application you make a system call into the operating system.  And the operating system can use whatever resources are available on that "system".  Be it a timer built into the processor (see Peter's comment for example) or a peripheral found on all motherboards(/chips), or both or many as there may be reasons to use different ones (dont care about wall clock time want time since the last call, a duration in some units, vs, wall clock time). Move from an x86 system to an ARM system to a MIPS system, etc you are not going to find the same time sources, but that doesnt mean the OS cannot keep time, duration nor wall clock.

Comment: I think the OP meant "register" not "registry", based on the 2nd comment.  IDK if it's a mistranslation from a non-English native language, but I've seen that misuse several times before in SO questions (usually with other signs of English as a second language).  It's definitely a confusing mistake, if that's what it is, though.